# Spatial data modelling tools

Tags: database-design, spatial

Is there anything like MySQL workbench for PostGIS? Something that supports SQL output and geometry types would be nice.

---

**CLARIFICATION:**

I am trying to implement the [Land Administration Domain Model](http://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://www.fig.net/pub/fig2011/ppt/ts02c/ts02c_elia_et_al_4880_ppt.pdf&ei=STp0T_PZI6WQiQeb7OTjDw&usg=AFQjCNHW5mBj1gK5H9yzz_N0TxxDVCS5oA&sig2=Ys9MFZdvOidqanxah0vDUA) and all I got are the specs ( UML diagrams). I need a tool that can create the models and output code that would create the tables. It needs to support geometry types as the LADM deals with parcels.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [GRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org) or [QGIS.](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/), open-source GIS applications.  You might be able to get what you want from one of them.

**EDIT:** I see you're after a data modelling tool with support for spatial data types.  I can't see any specific reference with basic google-fu.  You may be stuck with building your database model using `CREATE TABLE` statements and then reverse engineering them into a modelling tool for documentation.

If you have Visio Professional, the database modelling feature of that has a passably good database reverse engineering feature that will work OK with anything that supports an ODBC driver.

Another option might be to get an extensible tool such as Sparx Enterprise Architect and frig the metamodel.  However, this might be more work than building your database by hand.

Comment: Ah no. What I want are tools for designing spatial database schemas.

Comment: @R.K. - you mean a data modelling tool that supports spatial data types?

Comment: Yup. Preferably one that supports Postgresql/PostGIS as I'll most probably be using that database. Sorry for the ambiguity. Revised the question.

Comment: @R.K.  Maybe one of the more upmarket ones like PowerDesigner might do that, but it's quite pricey.